# Whitelist all IP/ Ray Dehler method does not work any longer

Tags: security, ip-whitelisting

There are 2 parts to my question

Traditionally, while developing and distributing Salesforce mobile apps for beta testing and feedback, I've used the [Ray Dehler method for whitelisting all IP addresses](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/enable-all-trusted-ip-ranges-for-a-salesforce-org.html) - it helps when you do not know the IP of the beta users (IP addresses typically change dynamically for mobile users for a lot of carriers globally).

Ray Dehler package is  a small utility ([unmanaged package](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tF0000000JHh6)) which basically adds all IP prefixes to the Salesforce whitelist.

[image]

A) This method worked great until about Spring or Winter 15 releases and after that, it stopped working. Since then, it **does not show the 'Load iFrames' button** which is the first step needed to generate the IP prefixes for whitelisting.

Has anyone been able to get this working on their orgs after the Spring/ Winter 15 release?

[image]

B) Regardless of A), is there any other script/ mechanism to whitelist all IP combinations you're aware of which does work with latest Salesforce release?

Of course, re-writing this utility can be done in a few hours but I wanted to check if there's anything already available rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Updated here: http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/whitelist-all-ips-for-salesforce-chrome-extension.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below code

```
var startingPoint = 0; 
var endpoint = 0; 

openPage(); 
function openPage() 
{ 
endpoint = startingPoint + 1; 
var win = window.open('https://ap2.salesforce.com/05G/e?IpStartAddress=' + startingPoint + '.0.0.0&IpEndAddress=' + endpoint + '.255.255.255&isdtp=vw',600,600); 
win.onload = function() 
{ 
win.document.getElementsByName('save')[0].click();
win.onunload = function() 
{ 
win.close(); 
startingPoint = startingPoint + 2; 
if(startingPoint <= 255) 
{ 
openPage(); 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

**Special thanks to MVP Ankit Arora** ([Reference](http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2016/01/how-to-whitelist-all-ips-in-salesforce.html):)

Comment: Thank you - this helps. I made some updates and generalised it for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I like how it's called the "Ray Dehler" method :)

It works as a Chrome extension now also: http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/whitelist-all-ips-for-salesforce-chrome-extension.html